# Prove that $\sum\limits_{r \mathop= 0}^n \frac {(-1)^r} {r!(n-r)!} = 0$

Tags: summation

I wish to prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{r \mathop= 0}^n \frac {(-1)^r} {r!(n-r)!} = 0$

It is plain when $n$ is an odd integer. How might one go about proving it generally?

Comment: well, it can be rearranged to converge to any number

Comment: @SalmonKiller But it is a finite sum!

Comment: it can also me made to diverge.

Comment: @SalmonKiller Not really: it is **a finite** sum: it cannot diverge.

Comment: @Timbuc It converges conditionally, which means that it can also be rearranged to diverge as well.

Comment: @SalmonKiller You're missing the tiny, **huge** detail that this is **A FINITE** sum: it can **not** diverge! There is not much case of talking of absolute, conditional, etc. *convergence* here: it is FINITE !

Comment: @SalmonKiller: No, that isn't true at all. It's a finite sum; the sum of finitely many real numbers is a real number.

Comment: @SalmonKiller The theorem you are thinking of only applies to infinite sums.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{r \mathop= 0}^n \frac {(-1)^r} {r!(n-r)!}=\frac 1{n!}\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r\binom n r
$$
Now
$$(1-1)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r{n\choose r}=0$$
Hence
$$\sum_{r \mathop= 0}^n \frac {(-1)^r} {r!(n-r)!}=\frac 1{n!}\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r\binom n r=0
$$

Answer (score 3):

Details are left to you:

$$\frac1{r!(n-r)!}=\frac1{n!}\binom nr\implies$$

$$\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{(-1)^r}{r!(n-r)!}=\frac1{n!}\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr(-1)^r=\frac1{n!}\cdot0=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $$\frac{1}{(n-r)! r!} =\frac{1}{n!} {n\choose r}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate a bit on the other answers. As noted, $$ \frac 1 {(n-r)!r!} = \frac 1{n!}\binom n r,$$ thus, your sum equals to $$\frac 1{n!}\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r\binom n r,$$ so it is enough to prove that $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r\binom n r = 0.$$ Now, as you noticed yourself, it's quite obvious for odd $n$'s, but a bit less obvious for even ones. But, if you draw Pascal's triangle, statement reveals itself to be true. It also reveals that you can use identity $$\binom n r = \binom {n-1}{r-1} + \binom {n-1} r$$ to rewrite your sum. Now we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r\binom n r
     &= 1 + \sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(-1)^r\binom n r + (-1)^n \\
     &= 1 + \sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(-1)^r\binom {n-1}{r-1} +\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(-1)^r\binom {n-1}{r} + (-1)^n \\
     &= 1 + \sum_{r=0}^{n-2}(-1)^{r+1}\binom {n-1}{r} +\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(-1)^r\binom {n-1}{r} + (-1)^n \\
     &= 1 + \left(-\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{r}\binom {n-1}{r} - (-1)^n\right) +\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}(-1)^r\binom {n-1}{r} - 1\right) + (-1)^n \\
     &= 0
\end{aligned}$$